# Get text in custom adapter from another activity

Tags: android

In main activity, I use this code but error nullErrorException:

```
View v = lvContent.getChildAt(1); //lvcontent is listview of MainActivity
EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edContent); //edContent is EditText of custom adapter      
et.getText().toString();
```

When this code then don't error. But i don't known how to get text at a position of EditText:

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_note_check_edit, null);
EditText et = (EditText) child.findViewById(R.id.edContent);        
et.getText().toString();
```

This is layout custom adapter: view_note_check_edit.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivMove"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_move"
     />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edContent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: This is because your `EditText` is in `view_note_check_edit.xml` file and in your first code you are trying to find it by `ListView` content.

Comment: Has lvContent been intialized? If it has, please post the code

Comment: hi, i have public static edContent.

Comment: i also intialize: viewNoteAdapter = new ViewNoteAdapter(this,R.layout.view_note_check_edit, viewNote);
lvContent.setAdapter(viewNoteAdapter);